# "default: ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.22.3" but NumPy 1.22.3 is properly installed

Tags: python, numpy, pip, vagrant

I'm trying to install Vagrant through the command `vagrant up` but at some point I get these errors:

```
default: ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.22.0 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.22.1 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.22.2 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.22.3 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.22.4 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.23.0 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.23.0rc1 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.23.0rc2 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.23.0rc3 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.23.1 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.23.2 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.23.3 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.23.4 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.23.5 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.24.0 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.24.0rc1 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.24.0rc2 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.24.1 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.24.2 Requires-Python >=3.8; 1.24.3 Requires-Python >=3.8
    default: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.22.3 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, 1.18.4, 1.18.5, 1.19.0, 1.19.1, 1.19.2, 1.19.3, 1.19.4, 1.19.5, 1.20.0, 1.20.1, 1.20.2, 1.20.3, 1.21.0, 1.21.1, 1.21.2, 1.21.3, 1.21.4, 1.21.5, 1.21.6)
    default: ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.22.3
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

I've tried to check my NumPy version (`pip show numpy`) and I've got this result:

```
Name: numpy
Version: 1.22.3
Summary: NumPy is the fundamental package for array computing with Python.
Home-page: https://www.numpy.org
Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.
Author-email:
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\userName\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: amrlib, bertopic, blis, contourpy, gensim, h5py, hdbscan, hnswlib, ImageHash, Keras-Preprocessing, matplotlib, numba, opt-einsum, pandas, pandas-profiling, patsy, phik, PyWavelets, scikit-learn, scipy, seaborn, sentence-transformers, spacy, stanfordnlp, stanza, statsmodels, tensorboard, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub, thinc, top2vec, torchvision, transformers, umap-learn, visions, wordcloud
```

In other words, the requested version is properly installed